# Matrix calculation gets slower after each iteration in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, large-data-volumes

I have a 1024*1024*51 matrix. I'll do calculations to change some value of the matrix within for loops (change the value of matrix for each iteration). I find that the computing speed gets slower and slower and finally my computer gets into trouble.However the size of the matrix doesn't change. Anyone can shed some light on this problem?

```
function ActiveContours3D(method,grad,im,mu,nu,lambda1,lambda2,TimeSteps)
epsilon = 10e-10;
tic
fid=fopen('Chr18_z_25of25tiles-C=0_c0_n000.raw','rb','ieee-le');   
Xdim = 1024;
Ydim = 1024;
Zdim = 51;
A = fread(fid,[Xdim Ydim*Zdim],'int16');
A = double(A);
size_of_A = size(A)
for(i=1:Zdim)
    u0_color(:,:,i) = A(1 : Xdim , (i-1)*Ydim+1 : i*Ydim);
end
fclose(fid)

time = toc

[M,N,P,color] = size(u0_color);
size(u0_color );
u0_color = double(u0_color);    % Convert u0_color values to double;
u0 = u0_color(:,:,:,1);           % Define the Grayscale volumetric image.
u0_color = uint8(u0_color);     % Necessary for color visualization
x = 1:M;
y = 1:N;
z = 1:P;
dx = 1
dy = 1
dz = 1
dim_approx = 2*M*N*P / sqrt(M*N*P);
if(method == 'Explicit')
    dt = 0.9 / ((2*mu/(dx^2)) + (2*mu/(dy^2)) + (2*mu/(dz^2)))    % 90% CFL
elseif(method == 'Implicit')
    dt = (10e7) * 0.9 / ((2*mu/(dx^2)) + (2*mu/(dy^2)) + (2*mu/(dz^2)))
end
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);
x0 = (M+1)/2;
y0 = (N+1)/2;
z0 = (P+1)/2;
r0 = min(min(M,N),P)/3;
phi = sqrt((X-x0).^2 + (Y-y0).^2 + (Z-z0).^2) - r0; 
phi_visualize = phi;            % Use this for visualization in 3D
phi = permute(phi,[2,1,3]);     % Use this for computations in 3D
write_to_binary_file(phi_visualize,0);       % record initial conditions

tic

for(n=1:TimeSteps)
n

c1 = C1_3d(u0,phi);
c2 = C2_3d(u0,phi);

% x
phi_xp = [phi(2:M,:,:); phi(M,:,:)];      % vertical concatenation
phi_xm = [phi(1,:,:);   phi(1:M-1,:,:)];        % (since x values are rows)
                        % cat(1,A,B) is the same as [A;B]
Dx_m = (phi - phi_xm)/dx;           % first derivatives
Dx_p = (phi_xp - phi)/dx;

Dxx = (Dx_p - Dx_m)/dx;     % second derivative

% y
phi_yp = [phi(:,2:N,:) phi(:,N,:)];       % horizontal concatenation
phi_ym = [phi(:,1,:)   phi(:,1:N-1,:)];         % (since y values are columns)
                        % cat(2,A,B) is the same as [A,B]
Dy_m = (phi - phi_ym)/dy;
Dy_p = (phi_yp - phi)/dy;

Dyy = (Dy_p - Dy_m)/dy;

% z
phi_zp = cat(3,phi(:,:,2:P),phi(:,:,P));
phi_zm = cat(3,phi(:,:,1)  ,phi(:,:,1:P-1));

Dz_m = (phi - phi_zm)/dz;
Dz_p = (phi_zp - phi)/dz;

Dzz = (Dz_p - Dz_m)/dz;

% x,y,z
Dx_0 = (phi_xp - phi_xm) / (2*dx);
Dy_0 = (phi_yp - phi_ym) / (2*dy);
Dz_0 = (phi_zp - phi_zm) / (2*dz);

phi_xp_yp = [phi_xp(:,2:N,:) phi_xp(:,N,:)];
phi_xp_ym = [phi_xp(:,1,:)   phi_xp(:,1:N-1,:)];
phi_xm_yp = [phi_xm(:,2:N,:) phi_xm(:,N,:)];
phi_xm_ym = [phi_xm(:,1,:)   phi_xm(:,1:N-1,:)];

phi_xp_zp = cat(3,phi_xp(:,:,2:P),phi_xp(:,:,P));
phi_xp_zm = cat(3,phi_xp(:,:,1)  ,phi_xp(:,:,1:P-1));
phi_xm_zp = cat(3,phi_xm(:,:,2:P),phi_xm(:,:,P));
phi_xm_zm = cat(3,phi_xm(:,:,1)  ,phi_xm(:,:,1:P-1));

phi_yp_zp = cat(3,phi_yp(:,:,2:P),phi_yp(:,:,P));
phi_yp_zm = cat(3,phi_yp(:,:,1)  ,phi_yp(:,:,1:P-1));
phi_ym_zp = cat(3,phi_ym(:,:,2:P),phi_ym(:,:,P));
phi_ym_zm = cat(3,phi_ym(:,:,1)  ,phi_ym(:,:,1:P-1));    


if(grad == 'Dirac')
    Grad = DiracDelta(phi);                  % Dirac delta    
    %Grad = 1;
elseif(grad == 'Grad ')
    Grad = (((Dx_0.^2)+(Dy_0.^2)+(Dz_0.^2)).^(1/2));   % |grad phi|
end

if(method == 'Explicit')
    % CURVATURE:   *mu*k|grad phi|*   (central differences):
    K = zeros(M,N,P);

    Dxy = (phi_xp_yp - phi_xp_ym - phi_xm_yp + phi_xm_ym) / (4*dx*dy);
    Dxz = (phi_xp_zp - phi_xp_zm - phi_xm_zp + phi_xm_zm) / (4*dx*dz);
    Dyz = (phi_yp_zp - phi_yp_zm - phi_ym_zp + phi_ym_zm) / (4*dy*dz);

    K = ( (Dx_0.^2).*Dyy - 2*Dx_0.*Dy_0.*Dxy + (Dy_0.^2).*Dxx ...
        + (Dx_0.^2).*Dzz - 2*Dx_0.*Dz_0.*Dxz + (Dz_0.^2).*Dxx ... 
        + (Dy_0.^2).*Dzz - 2*Dy_0.*Dz_0.*Dyz + (Dz_0.^2).*Dyy) ./ ((Dx_0.^2 + Dy_0.^2 + Dz_0.^2).^(3/2) + epsilon);

    phi_temp = phi + dt * Grad .* ( mu.*K + lambda1*(u0 - c1).^2 - lambda2*(u0 - c2).^2 );

elseif(method == 'Implicit')
    C1x = 1 ./ sqrt(Dx_p.^2 + Dy_0.^2 + Dz_0.^2 + (10e-7)^2);
    C2x = 1 ./ sqrt(Dx_m.^2 + Dy_0.^2 + Dz_0.^2 + (10e-7)^2);
    C3y = 1 ./ sqrt(Dx_0.^2 + Dy_p.^2 + Dz_0.^2 + (10e-7)^2);
    C4y = 1 ./ sqrt(Dx_0.^2 + Dy_m.^2 + Dz_0.^2 + (10e-7)^2);
    C5z = 1 ./ sqrt(Dx_0.^2 + Dy_0.^2 + Dz_p.^2 + (10e-7)^2);
    C6z = 1 ./ sqrt(Dx_0.^2 + Dy_0.^2 + Dz_m.^2 + (10e-7)^2);

    % m = (dt/(dx*dy)) * Grad .* mu;        % 2D
    m = (dt/(dx*dy)) * Grad .* mu;
    C = 1 + m.*(C1x + C2x + C3y + C4y + C5z + C6z);

    C1x_2x = C1x.*phi_xp + C2x.*phi_xm;
    C3y_4y = C3y.*phi_yp + C4y.*phi_ym;
    C5z_6z = C5z.*phi_zp + C6z.*phi_zm;

    phi_temp = (1 ./ C) .* ( phi + m.*(C1x_2x+C3y_4y) + (dt*Grad).*(lambda1*(u0 - c1).^2) - (dt*Grad).*(lambda2*(u0 - c2).^2) );
end

phi = phi_temp;

phi_visualize =  permute(phi,[2,1,3]);
write_to_binary_file(phi_visualize,n);     % record

end

time = toc

n = n
T = dt*n

clear
clear all
```

Comment: That's not a particularly big matrix provided you're not still using a 32-bit OS or have only a little RAM. If you show us the code in question we might be able to help. Better yet, spend a bit of time and create a [small example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that still demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hi, I've posted the code..It's is used for segmentation in 3D data.Do you have any idea why it does't work well for large volume of data?

Comment: There's an awful lot going on there. Your code isn't runnable so I can't help much. I can't see anything in the big `for` loop that is growing or not preallocated (`u0_color` at the top isn't though – how big is that?). How many iterations are you running? Where and when in the code does it bog down? In what iteration? Start debugging and printing out variables. Try running with the [profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) (`profview` is a GUI interface, but you may want to use `profile`).

Answer (score 0):

In general Matlab keeps track of all the variables in the form of matrix. When you work with lot of variables with many dimensions the RAM memory will be allocated for storing this variable. Hence on working with lots of variables that is gonna run for multiple iterations it is better to clear the variable from the memory. To do so use the command

**clear variable_name_1, variable_name_2,... variable_name_3;**

Although keeping all the variables keeps the code to look organised, however when you face such issues try clearing the unwanted variables.

Check this link to use clear command in detail: http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/clear.html